# Accessing Instance Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller

I am just looking to seek some clarification to accessing Instance variables within its class (apologies if this is really basic).

My example is that  I have a recipe controller and within it I have many actions but in paticular I have an INDEX and a SHOW action

```
def index
@q = Recipe.search(params[:q])
@q.build_condition
end
```

@q searches my Recipe model based on the params passed through my search form

i want to show the results on a different page to start (will look at AJAX option later), so in my SHOW action could I do this

```
 def show
 @searchresults = @q.result(:distinct => true)
 end
```

I think this is valid but if not I am going wrong somewhere. Can anyone advise or offer some constructive advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use instance variable like this because they both have different action and will get called for the different request.

However following will work

```
def index
  @q = Recipe.search(params[:q])
  @q.build_condition
  show
end

def show
  #Following line will work as we are calling this method in index 
  #and so we can use instance variable of index method in the show methos 
  @searchresults = @q.result(:distinct => true)
end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, so if for example i placed search results instance variable within a results action i would just call results in my index..think you have cleared things up for me here

Answer (score 3):

your object or class should have the following methods:

- `@foo.instance_variables` - this will list the names of the instance variables for `@foo`
- `@foo.instance_variable_get` - this will get the value of an instance variable for `@foo`

  - ex: `@foo.instance_variable_get("@bar")` - this would get the value of the instance variable named `@bar` for `@foo`